# Merge nodes of the same kind to a single node

Tags: c#

I'm trying to merge 2 `Nodes` of the same kind into a single `Node`

So by having both `Nodes` like this

```
<Clubs>
  <SPE>Accepted</Community>
  <SCU>Accepted</SCU>
</Clubs>
```

and this

```
<Clubs>
  <BUS>Declined</BUS>
</Clubs>
```

it will become like this

```
<Clubs>
  <SPE>Accepted</SPE>
  <SCU>Accepted</SCU>
  <BUS>Declined</BUS>
</Clubs>
```

How could i achieve such thing?

Comment: What have you done so far, and what problems are you having with your current attempts?  Are you using an XML parser, if so, which one?  Have you parsed the data into in memory objects successfully?  Can you successfully write the objects out once you've merged the in memory objects?  Do you know how to merge the objects once they're parsed into in memory objects?

Comment: @Servy well, i have made it by moving the `BUS` from the second `Node` to the first and then deleting the second `Node` but it's a long complicated process and hard to use.. so i need something less complicated

Comment: Please include your existing solution, and explain, specifically, in what way it is not satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you

```
           XmlDocument myDocument = new XmlDocument();
           myDocument.Load(XMLFile);
           var NodeToadd = myDocument.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(nodeVariant => nodeVariant.Name == "Clubs").SelectMany(o => o.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>()).ToList();
           var nodeToDelete = myDocument.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlElement>().Where(nodeVariant => nodeVariant.Name == "Clubs");
           foreach (var m in nodeToDelete)
           {
               myDocument.RemoveChild(m);
           }
             XmlNode newNode = myDocument.CreateElement("Clubs");
            foreach(var m in NodeToadd)
            {
            newNode.AppendChild(m);
            }
            myDocument.AppendChild(newNode);
            myDocument.Save(XMLFile);
```